# Why is my pdf not appearing in the code I wrote it to appear for?

Tags: html, wordpress, pdf, iframe, elementor

I want to display a pdf on my wordpress website that's already downloaded onto the website (stored in the media category). Here's the code I have to display it thus far:`your text`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
<head>
    <meta charset ="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content   ="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>request modifcations doc</title>
    <style>
    #alterationpdf{
        width: 85%;
        height:975px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<iframe id = "alterationpdf" "Application_to_Perform_Alterations.pdf" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I put the code into an html element with the Elementor editor, one of the wordpress plugins. I was expecting window in the website with the pdf inside to pop up. Instead, there was a window with the correct size and dimmensions but no pdf inside, just an error that says that the page I'm looking for doesn't exist.

Tried checking the name of the pdf but other than that I literally don't know what to do. It should be working, especially since the window pops up. I've tried using different images, .jpgs, in place of the pdf and it works. IDK what's going on.

Comment: Where is the pdf in your files? Also if you could use the *inspect* tool on your page and go to the console, maybe you'll be given an error that you can use to start to track down it.

Comment: i think you should put the URL of the PDF file in a `src` property of the iframe. like: `<iframe src="myPDFhere.pdf"></iframe>`

Comment: There are some mistakes and missing things in your **iframe** tag… try: `<iframe id="alterationpdf" src="Application_to_Perform_Alterations.pdf" frameborder="0"></iframe>` and be sure that in the `src` value, you have **the correct path** with your file name.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your Iframe is missing a src attribute. You have put the link, without it. It should look like this :

```
<iframe id = "alterationpdf" src="Application_to_Perform_Alterations.pdf" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

As for the url for the src attribute, I believe it is wrong. Since you've uploaded the PDF throught the media library, you should have a link in the wp-content/uploads.

To get the media URL, go to the media library. Select the PDF. On the right side of the page, you will see a tab containing informations about the file
Exemple :
[File's information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufH6W.png)

You can copy the link and put it inside your IFrame src attribute.

Now, about Elementor. Creating an HTML element and adding your code was the right approach. However, you don't need all of the structure, just the IFrame tag. The `<html>, <head>, <body>` will already be there, you don't need them.

The HTML element is simply a way to add HTML, it doesn't create a whole new page, it just place your HTML code inside the rest of the code. By adding all the unnecessary structure, you will basically add it inside a div, which is a no-no !